# javascript number regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've come up with this regular expression to validate a javascript number according to the specification:

```
(-|\+|)(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)([eE](-|\+|)\d+)?
```

As far as I can think of, these are valid numbers in js:

123,123.3, .3, -123, -.3, -.3e-2, -.3e+2, +.2e2... and so forth.

I've been trying to find a verified regular expression on the internet so that I could compare my solution but to no avail.

Could anyone tell me if my approach is correct or give me a better solution?

[Link to test my solution](https://regex101.com/r/tK6hZ5/1)

Comment: I don't get it, what's wrong with `isNaN` ?

Comment: it's a regular expression not intended to be used in js

Comment: And yet, you seem to be trying to match valid numbers in js ?

Comment: no, that's not the point. The point is I want to figure out a regular expression that could validate a js number

Comment: @acontell what's the end goal of validating js-valid numbers?

Comment: @royhowie I'm not trying to validate numbers using this regular expression. I just saw the specification and was wondering how the regular expression underneath would look like. Learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using [`isNan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is the correct way of checking numbers in JavaScript, you can also validate floating point numbers with `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` regex (taken from [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)).

*Consider using appropriate anchors though!* (`^` for string start, `$` for string end).

[Demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/wG9wK4/2).